# after adding Public Route and Private Route app not working

Tags: reactjs

After adding PublicRoute and PrivateRoute my app not working popup login and signup. It displaying a blank screen. Before adding PublicRoute and PrivateRoute, my app working fine with Route.

The App has an initial home page when I click on the Merchant button it should popup for the login page. Please find the below screenshot.
[image]
But it displays with a blank screen. Please find below screenshot
[image]

Please help me to fix this issue.

AppRouter.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router, Route , Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { HomePage } from '../components/HomePage';
import DashboardPage from '../components/DashboardPage';
import StartLogin from '../components/StartLogin';
import { UserForm } from '../components/UserForm';
import PublicRoute from './PublicRouter';
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRouter';
 
export const history = createHistory()
 
const AppRouter = () => (
    <Router history={history}>
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <PublicRoute path="/" component={HomePage} exact={true}/>
                <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={DashboardPage} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>
);
 
export default AppRouter;
```

PublicRoute.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
 
export const PublicRoute = ( {
    isAuthenticated,
    component: Component,
    ...rest}) => (
    <Route {...rest}  component={(props) => (
        isAuthenticated ? (
            <div>
                <Redirect to='/dashboard' />
            </div>
        ) : (
            <Component {...props} />
        )
    )}/>
);
 
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.merchLogin
})
 
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PublicRoute);
```

PrivateRoute.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { HomePage } from '../components/HomePage';
 
export const PrivateRoute = ( { 
    isAuthenticated,
    component: Component,
    ...rest}) => (
    <Route {...rest}  component={(props) => (
        isAuthenticated ? (
            <div>
                <HomePage />
                <Component {...props} />
            </div>
        ) : (
            <Redirect to='/' />
        )
    )}/>
);
 
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.merchLogin
})
 
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

Comment: In these cases I like to simply add different routes in the switcher, in this case based on wether or not the user is authenticated, with a conditional `isAuthenticated && (map over authenticated routes)` and `!isAuthenticated && (map over unauthenticated routes)`

Answer (score 0):

Remove isAuthenticated from PublicRoute.js

```
<Route path="/" component={HomePage} exact={true}/>
```

Comment: try  this <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />

Comment: here is git link: https://github.com/Poorna86/temple_managment.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any additional info.